# LINQ to SQL database in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I have created a database in Visual Studio with LINQ to SQL. When I run program and edit the database, I save it with this:

```
Validate();
tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
data.SubmitChanges();
```

It saves while within the program, but when I close it and run it again the changes are lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008 .mdf file

Comment: Is the .mdf file included in your project?  If so, what is it's Build Action set to?

Comment: I opened my .mdf database file in Server Explorer then i added new Linq to Sql file. In Linq to Sql .dbml I drag and drop my tables and it asked me to save file into project i clicked yess. Then from data source I selected new data source then Object. Then drag and droped datagirdview into the form. This is all done and .mdf file is included in project Build action is Content ???

Comment: What about the "Copy to Output Directory" property?  I think what might be happening, is that when you run the program, it copies an _empty_ database, overwriting the one that you saved data in previously.

Comment: Yess I know about making a new copy from my database and then makes changes to the fresh copy of database but what is solution. My copy to output directory property is copy always. I changed it to Do not copy but now its giving me an error:
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file \bin\Debug\ITPDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: I copied my database in debug folder and now its working thanks a lot :)